# G Suite - Auto Sync added calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-workspace

Every new user within my organization is subscribed to a calendar using the GSuite API's containing workplace broad events (office closed etc.)

```
CalendarListResource.InsertRequest insertNewCalendar = CalendarList.Insert("<calendar>")
CalendarListEntry insertedCalendar = insertNewCalendar.Execute();
```

This works fine, and shows up in the "Other Calendars" list on the gmail calendars website as expected.

The question is: How do I then, whether programmatically or otherwise (domain wide settings etc., prefer programmatically at subscription time), set it to sync by default (https://calendar.google.com/calendar/syncselect) to iphones/androids who add the domain email to their phone?

Comment: You might want to check this documentation - [Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#sample_code), this describes how to implement "incremental synchronization" of calendar data. Using this method, you can keep data for all calendar collections in sync while saving bandwidth. Hope this helps.

Comment: I saw that, however, I'm talking about the built in Apple / Android Calendars not seeing shared resources unless you go to the syncselect website. Getting calendar events onto the calendar is not my issue.